# Mongoid Criteria: How to count number of documents that have a field with specific value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Criteria is as follows:

```
#<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {"_id"=>{"$in"=>["535988c59bb8f9128c000001", 
                             "53598a439bb8f9f211000001",    
                             "536a9300ae4da1b0a9000002"]}}
  options:  {:limit=>5}
  class:    User
  embedded: false>
```

I want to traverse these users and get a count of how many have attribute `is_active: true`.
I'm thinking there has to be another way rather than doing `users.each do |user|` and keep a running count of whether the user met that criteria. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have that criteria in a variable:

```
query = User.where(:id.in => ids).limit(5)
```

then you can add another condition by calling `where`:

```
query = query.where(:is_active => true)
```

and then count them:

```
n = query.count
```

Comment: I had tried this before but it would only return me a count of 0. It wasn't until I realized that I was checking for a string not a boolean. Thanks!